# How to use the fillna method in a for loop

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, feature-engineering, kaggle

I am working on a housing dataset.  In a list of columns (Garage, Fireplace, etc), I have values called `NA` which just means that the particular house in question does not have that feature (Garage, Fireplace).  It doesn't mean that the value is missing/unknown.  However, Python interprets this as `NaN`, which is wrong.  To come across this, I want to replace this value `NA` with `XX` to help Python distinguish it from NaN values.  Because there is a whole list of them, I want use a for loop to accomplish this in a few lines of code:

```
na_data = ['Alley', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType',
           'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature']

for i in range(len(na_data)):
    train[i] = train[i].fillna('XX')
```

I know this isn't the correct way of doing it as it is giving me a `KeyError: 0`.  This is kinda like a pseudocode way of doing it to visualize what I'm trying to accomplish.  What is the way to automate `fillna('XX')` on this list of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

And you don't need to write all the columns you can iterate over the columns name simply.

```
for col in train:
    train[col].replace("NA","XX",inplace=True)
```

You can do it on all the dataset in one line:

```
train.replace("NA","XX", inplace=True)
```

Or on specific columns:

```
for cols in na_data:
    train[col].replace("NA","XX",inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yea but its not every column in train.  It is a specific list of columns organized in `na_data`

Comment: I edited my response

Comment: How would you do this for two instances (strings) e.g. replace "Unknown" with "Nan" and also replace "Not Found" with "Nan"?

Answer (score 1):

While `replace` is a valid approach, it can be inefficient and slow on a large scale - see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012339/using-replace-efficiently-in-pandas).

You should instead use `map` to encode `NA` as `XX` - perhaps something like this:

```
na_data = ['Alley', ...,'Fence', 'MiscFeature']
for col in na_data:
   train[col]= train[col].map({'NA':'XX'})
```

Comment: How would you do this for two instances (strings) e.g. replace "Unknown" with "Nan" and also replace "Not Found" with "Nan"?

Comment: You could extend the dict to include other instances - e.g. `{ 'Unknown':'Nan','Not Found':'Nan'}`. Beware of behaviour when constructing your dict - any key/value pairs excluded in the dict will be mapped to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works this way:

```py
# data_train.columns
na_data = ['Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents','Self_Employed','Credit_History','Loan_Amount_Term']

for i in na_data:
    data_train[i].fillna(data_train[i].mode()[0], inplace=True)
    print(i)
```

These result are from `print(i)`, just for confirmation.

```
#Gender
#Married
#Dependents
#Self_Employed
#Credit_History
#Loan_Amount_Term
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is correct, replaces with mode value of the column rather than single value..